# Reliable way of getting the exact decimals from any number

Tags: lua, luajit

I'm having problem returning spesific amount of decimal numbers from this function, i would like it to get that info from "dec" argument, but i'm stuck with this right now.
Edit: Made it work with the edited version bellow but isn't there a better way?

```
local function remove_decimal(t, dec)
    if type(dec) == "number" then
        for key, num in pairs(type(t) == "table" and t or {}) do
            if type(num) == "number" then
                local num_to_string = tostring(num)
                local mod, d = math.modf(num)
                -- find only decimal numbers
                local num_dec = num_to_string:sub(#tostring(mod) + (mod == 0 and num < 0 and 3 or 2))

                if dec <= #num_dec then
                    -- return amount of deciamls in the num by dec
                    local r = d < 0 and "-0." or "0."
                    local r2 = r .. num_dec:sub(1, dec)

                    t[key] = mod + tonumber(r2)
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return t
end
```

By passing the function bellow i want a result like this:

```
result[1] > 0.12
result[2] > -0.12
result[3] > 123.45
result[4] > -1.23

local result = remove_decimal({0.123, -0.123, 123.456, -1.234}, 2)

print(result[1])
print(result[2])
print(result[3])
print(result[4])
```

I tried this but it seems to only work with one integer numbers and if number is 12.34 instead of 1.34 e.g, the decimal place will be removed and become 12.3. Using other methods

```
local d = dec + (num < 0 and 2 or 1)
local r = tonumber(num_to_string:sub(1, -#num_to_string - d)) or 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good approach is to find the position of the decimal point (the dot, `.`) and then extract a substring starting from the first character to the dot's position plus how many digits you want:

```lua
local function truncate(number, dec)
    local strnum = tostring(number)
    local i, j = string.find(strnum, '%.')
    
    if not i then
        return number
    end
    
    local strtrn = string.sub(strnum, 1, i+dec)
    return tonumber(strtrn)
end
```

Call it like this:

```lua
print(truncate(123.456, 2))
print(truncate(1234567, 2))
```

```
123.45
1234567
```

---

To bulk-truncate a set of numbers:

```lua
local function truncate_all(t, dec)
    for key, value in pairs(t) do
        t[key] = truncate(t[key], dec)
    end
    return t
end
```

Usage:

```lua
local result = truncate_all({0.123, -0.123, 123.456, -1.234}, 2)

for key, value in pairs(result) do
    print(key, value)
end
```

```
1   0.12
2   -0.12
3   123.45
4   -1.23
```

Answer (score 1):

One could use the function [string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format) which is similar to the printf functions from C language. If one use the format "%.2f" the resulting string will contain 2 decimals, if one use "%.3f" the resulting string will be contain 3 decimals, etc. The idea is to dynamically create the format "%.XXXf" corresponding to the number of decimal needed by the function. Then call the function [string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format) with the newly created format string to generate the string "123.XXX". The last step would be to convert back the string to a number with the function [tonumber](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_tonumber).

Note that if one want the special character `%` to be preserved when [string.format](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.format) is called, you need to write `%%`.

```
function KeepDecimals (Number, DecimalCount)
  local FloatFormat = string.format("%%.%df", DecimalCount)
  local String      = string.format(FloatFormat, Number)
  return tonumber(String)
end
```

The behavior seems close to what the OP is looking for:

```
for Count = 1, 5 do
  print(KeepDecimals(1.123456789, Count))
end
```

This code should print the following:

```
1.1
1.12
1.123
1.1235
1.12346
```

---

Regarding the initial code, it's quite straight-forward to integrate the provided solution. Note that I renamed the function to `keep_decimal` because in my understanding, the function will keep the requested number of decimals, and discard the rest.

```
function keep_decimal (Table, Count)
  local NewTable = {}
  local NewIndex = 1
  for Index = 1, #Table do
    NewTable[NewIndex] = KeepDecimal(Table[Index], Count)
    NewIndex = NewIndex + 1
  end
  return NewTable
end
```

Obviously, the code could be tested easily, simply by copy and pasting into a [Lua interpreter](https://replit.com/languages/lua).

```
Result = keep_decimal({0.123, -0.123, 123.456, -1.234}, 2)

for Index = 1, #Result do
  print(Result[Index])
end
```

This should print the following:

```
0.12
-0.12
123.46
-1.23
```

---

Edit due to the clarification of the need of `truncate`:

```
function Truncate (Number, Digits)
  local Divider = Digits * 10
  local TruncatedValue = math.floor(Number * Divider) / Divider
  return TruncatedValue
end
```

On my computer, the code is working as expected:

```
> Truncate(123.456, 2)
123.45
```

Comment: Thank you for the alternative answer but as you state yourself, it's not reliable, it would print 123.46 and not 123.45.

Comment: It's quite reliable, for most purposes 123.456's value if you need 2 digits is 123.46, not 123.45. You should be more precise, what you really want is "truncate" as opposition to "rounding".

Comment: `Divider = Digits * 10`? Shouldn't it be `Divider = 10 ^ Digits`?

Comment: Truncate, okay. But you are still rounding it? Anyway it's not what i was looking for, it's just not reliable